# Dll calling another dll with JNA

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, jna

let me try to explain my problem..

I have the following directory structure:

- main dir

  - src
  - ext
  - bin

Today the dlls are inside the folder "bin" and are working fine, but due to a requirement, I need to change to "ext" folder.

On application's startup, I am setting the jna.library.path and java.library.path in runtime:

```
// JNA
    System.setProperty("jna.library.path", myLibraryPath);
```

and

```
// JAVA
final Field usrPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("usr_paths");
usrPathsField.setAccessible(true);

final String[] paths = (String[])usrPathsField.get(null);

for(String path : paths) {
    if(path.equals(libraryPath)) {
        return;
    }
}

final String[] newPaths = Arrays.copyOf(paths, paths.length + 1);
newPaths[newPaths.length-1] = libraryPath;
usrPathsField.set(null, newPaths);
```

The code above sets the java.library.path after initialization.

I tried run it on line command as well:

```
-Djna.library.path=path_to_ext -Djava.library.path=path_to_ext
```

So, in my tests I detected that the problem occurs when I call a method from a dll, and this method, calls other method of another dll.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: JNA can only control the first level of lookup.  Once a DLL looks up another DLL, things revert to the system path after looking in the current directory (the directory in which the first DLL resides).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my question setting the environment variable HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Environment/Path to myLibraryPath.