# JNI: cannot find library in java.library.path when running JUnit

Tags: java, android, c++, junit, java-native-interface

I am using JUnit to test an android program that uses the JNI and depends on multiple .so files which are all in the same folder. When I run unit tests that call

```
System.loadLibrary("Name")
```

This statement throws the following error:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkerError: no libName in java.library.path
```

Based on the answers to other SO questions, I decided to try adding

```
-Djava.library.path=path/to/libs
```

as an argument to my emulator. This did not help anything. I even had my program print the value of java.library.path, and it included the correct path to my library, but somehow still threw the unsatisfiedLinkError. I can only conclude that something strange is happening as a result of running with JUnit, as when I run my program normally (as an android application), I have no such errors. What's going on?

Comment: I think this might be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396722/dll-calling-another-dll-with-jna ?

Comment: That solution appears to be Windows-specific, whereas I am trying to get my tests to work on OSX

Comment: The concept sounded the same: JNI calling a library, which in turn calls a library?

Comment: It turns out that my question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425591/robolectric-tanks-on-application-objects-that-load-jni-libraries-can-i-get-a-wo
The problem was due to using the Robolectric test framework, which has issues with running JNI code.